# how can i check greater number from list?

Tags: perl

sample data is this,who can i find greater number,whenever first and last digit suppose 0?

```
                                      '3.268160E-02',

                                           '2.433833E-02',

                                           '2.473959E-01',

                                           '4.960246E-06',

                                           '1.470189E-05',

                                           '1.527312E-05',

                                           '8.997553E+01',

                                           '8.981999E+01',

                                           '2.700648E+02',

                                           '2.656095E+02',

                                           '2.719822E+02',

                                           '2.695895E+02'
```

for example i have 2,4,3
i want to check that 2 is greater than 0,or 2 is greater than 4
i want to check that 4 is greater than 2,or 4 is greater than 3
i want to check that 3 is greater than 4,or 3 is greater than 0

how ?plz help me.

Comment: A bit simple : $t=0; foreach $table { $t = $_ if $_ gt $t }

Comment: Let me ask a very qualified question: WHAT?!
Please reread your question and then change it so we can understand it. Also, show [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat those as numbers, just do. Perl will do it automatically. You can either simple sort them:

```
my @sorted_list = sort { $a <=> $b } @numbers;
```

But keep in mind that sorting is expensive and costs way too much if you just want the max.

Or you can use [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) to find the greatest or smallest value.

```
use List::Util qw(max min);
say max (@numbers);
say min (@numbers);
```

Comment: Sorting a list of numbers to find the maximum or minimum ist a little more than **expensive**, it's simply **unnecessary**.